# java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I want to connect to webSocket, but an error occurs. How to resolve it? Or it may  be error on server side?

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
```

Code:

```
final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .get()
            .url("http://develop.by:8000")
           .build();

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

WebSocket webSocket = okHttpClient.newWebSocket(request, new WebSocketListener() {...}
```

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{develop.by:8000, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=develop.by/195.***.***.**:8000 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:205)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:227)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:212)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: see this https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3629

Comment: @Tigo2018 still dont understand how to resolve the issue on my side

Comment: Did you try .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)?

Answer (score 2):

according to [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3590) issue Disable gzip

```
   .header("Accept-Encoding", "identity")
```

Comment: This did not solve for me.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue while trying to upload some images to a server, on proper research, turned out the problem came from the server the application was connected to. From the key-value pairs of the form-data to be sent over the server, turned out some key was properly sending the images while others were not. I'll advise you do proper testing of the API links connected to, by Retrofit, using a tool such as Postman to determine if the server side is working correctly before deciding your next approach.